# Mysql --secure-file-priv on Windows

Tags: mysql

I installed Mysql on Windows using MySQL installer, then after the termination of the install process I have only access to Mysql 5.7 command line client, my first question is can't I access Mysql server ? 
then I try to load data from file usind Load data infile and it returns an error :

```
Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Anyone can help me find the solution ? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last time I installed mysql I didn't have that kind of issue. For the GUI part I was doing my stuff in the MySQL workbench if it can help... Did you double checked the options used at installation? maybe you removed some part of the install package by using custom options.

For the 2nd question, I think this post may help: [Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951468/error-code-1290-the-mysql-server-is-running-with-the-secure-file-priv-option)

It may be a privilege issue,so  maybe you can try `--skip-grant-tables` option as a quick and dirty workaround but doing so should be temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, 
indeed I MySQL server is located in 'C:\ Program Data\MySQL\ MySQL server version' , there I found the my.ini in which there is the file accepting the file to load .. when I put my file there, I got no problem