# MySQL --secure-file-priv

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import data from a txt file to MySQL using

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/path/to/file.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
```

However I am getting an error

```
[Err] 1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

I have done some searching but can't find anything specific to this error.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: You tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32737478/2518525) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31951468/2518525) ?

Comment: Nope as I didn't find those links. Doing it now. Thanks

Comment: Beauty! No probs man :)