# Export MySQL as CSV using Powershell

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I am trying to extract a certain table as csv using powershell, since this task is scheduled. Since using it in Powershell is basically the same I am showing you the commandline commands I tried using:

```
mysql --user=root --password=root apps_monitor -e "select * from board into outfile 'C:\Temp\export.text'"
```

And then I get the error:
The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement.

My question is how I disable this option. I tried editing the my-default.ini in the MySQL Server directory and adding

```
secure_file_priv=NULL
```

And

```
secure_file_priv=""
```

But both did not do anything upon restarting the mysql service. Can someone please help me with that thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951468/error-code-1290-the-mysql-server-is-running-with-the-secure-file-priv-option could help

Comment: I tried that without any change.