# How to take mysqldump of a table by filtering that table with join from another table column value?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export a data from a table, Here's an example tables,

```
# table
role_permission:

role_permissionID  roleID

      1               100
      2               101
      3               100


# table
role:

 roleID          organizationID 
  100                 3121
  200                 1212
```

Here, role permission table is linked with role table by roleID column.

I want to take a dump of role_permission table using `mysqldump` but only for **organizationID=3121**?

I know how to take dump of role table but not role permission table.

```
mysqldump --compact --no-create-info -u root -p RF role --where="organizationID=100" > role.mysql
```

Please do help?

Comment: use into out file

Comment: @nbk I am not very familiar with it, can you provide an example or some references And Is it not possible via mysqldump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use. The folder has to have write permissions and if You use  --secure-file-priv you will get an error 1250 and have to enable it

```
SELECT r1.*,r2.* 
FROM role_permission  r1 
     INNER JOIN role r2 ON r1.roleID = r2.roleID 
INTO DUMPFILE '/tmp/world';
```

Comment: I am getting this error that you mentioned, `OperationalError: (1290, 'The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement')`, and I don't have access to change settings in mysql hosted server.

Comment: yes you can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951468/error-code-1290-the-mysql-server-is-running-with-the-secure-file-priv-option

Comment: When I use this strategy, the json column data I am not able to import this csv file, I used INTO OUTFILE. Json data is not parsing when importing this exported data

Comment: the dumpfile should be a sql file and not a csvmake the comanf as it is and open the sql file